# How to send rosservice call message from a c++ package?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am writing a package written in c++ for ros-melodic on ubuntu 18.04.

I need to send service call to a node that takes 3 values as following service call from terminal to change LED color.

> $ rosservice call /set_led_color "red: ###
> green: ###
> blue: ##"

The node have service file definition under "node_name/srv" as
Color.srv
and its contents as following

> int64 red
> int64 green
> int64 blue
> --

And in node.py the service is coded as

> from omo_r1mini_bringup.srv import Color, ColorResponse

> rospy.Service('set_led_color', Color, self.save_led_color_service_handle)

> def save_led_color_service_handle(self, req):
> command = "$sCOLOR," + str(req.red) + ',' + str(req.green) + ',' + str(req.blue)
> self.ph.write_port(command)
> return ColorResponse()

I tried to initialize my service client by

> svc_client = n.serviceClient("/set_led_color", true);

however it is not working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382215/how-to-send-rosservice-call-message-from-a-c++-package?/) by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2021-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not add below lines in package.xml

> <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
> <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
> <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>

and then it is able to generate service header according to the service files defined in srv folder.

In my node.hpp file I added

> #include "r1mini_gui_teleop/Color.h"
> ...
> private:
> ...
> ros::ServiceClient serviceClient;   //Client node to call service
> my_node::Color serviceSetColor;  //Service set color

And in node.cpp file

> init(...){
> ...
> serviceClient = n.serviceClient<r1mini_gui_teleop::Color>("/set_led_color");
> }
> some function(...)
> ...
> serviceClient.call(serviceSetColor);

Solved my problem.

---

Originally posted by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) with karma: 60 on 2021-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0